# How do you get the "There's an app for that" achievement?

Tags: achievements, surgeon-simulator

How do you get the "There's an app for that" achievement on Surgeon Simulator Touch? The achievement description says:

> Get all the apps on the izac

But the game keeps telling me insufficient funds.

Answer (score -1):

Well on the I Zac there's free games and games you have to pay for using the I Zac credits. You may have to ask another question how do you get credits for the I Zac, but now until you get them you have to get the free games. Sorry if I couldn't help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arquade. When answering a question, please read the whole question and attempt to answer what's being asked as a whole.This answer seems to only answer the tittle question.